# Show 3 items based on a date that can be future and past

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that holds a date that can be either upcoming or past. I preferably want to see the 3 upcoming items. But if there aren't any, I want to show the ones that have already past, with the most recent first.

So if there are all future ones:

`future - future - future`

If there are only two future ones:

`past - future - future`

How should I achieve this in my model?

Comment: `I preferably want to see the 3 upcoming items.` what is meant by items here?

Comment: Sorry, title is misleading, I thought when writing the post that the use case with 3 records was sufficient for the example. So I want to show 3 records if they are all upcoming.

Comment: like a range by date?

Answer (score 0):

if is range that you want you can adapt this for your case.

```
month = Date.today

range = ["`users`.`created_at`>= '#{month.beginning_of_month}') AND (`users`.`created_at` <= '#{month.end_of_month}'"]

User.where(range)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple data manipulation with rails by rails .order method
ex: `Model.all.order('created_at DESC').limit(3)`

This will give you last 3 future records.